# Qt QDateTime toString("h:m:s ap") ap/a/AP/a missing

Tags: qt

I've noted the "ap/a/AP/a" is missing while converting a date to string. For "h:m:s ap", i.e., I get "11:5:42 ". The same happens for each of the "ap/a/AP/a" forms.

What I'm missing?

```
void DecoderBr1::recordOnFile(QDateTime dateTime, QByteArray ba)
{
    QString filename(dateTime.toString("yyyy MMMM dd@HH.mm.ss zzz ap"));
    filename.append(".log");

    Recorder recorder;
    recorder.recordFile(filename, ba);
}
```

Comment: could you please show your code?

Comment: Question edited to add code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your locale. Not every locale support AM/PM format.
For example, my default locale is "it_IT" and does not print "AM/PM". Setting another locale (e.g. "en_EN") instead works as expected.

```
QDateTime t = QDateTime::fromString("2015-07-16T19:20:30+01:00", Qt::ISODate);
QString st = t.toString("yyyy MMMM dd@HH.mm.ss zzz ap");
QString locale_st_HH = QLocale("en_EN").toString(t, "yyyy MMMM dd@HH.mm.ss zzz ap");     
QString locale_st_hh = QLocale("en_EN").toString(t, "yyyy MMMM dd@hh.mm.ss zzz ap");

qDebug() << st; 
// With italian locale does not print AM/PM
// "2015 luglio 16@19.20.30 000 "

qDebug() << locale_st_HH; 
// With en_EN locale it works
//"2015 July 16@19.20.30 000 pm"

qDebug() << locale_st_hh; 
// With en_EN locale it works
// With hh it prints 07 pm instead of 19 pm // Credits to @t3ft3l--i
//"2015 July 16@07.20.30 000 pm"
```

Comment: Because you write HH?HH the hour with a leading zero (00 to 23, even with AM/PM display)

Comment: At your example you change own locale and dont swap it again.

Comment: @t3ft3l--i No, also with H prints 19

Comment: H = the hour without a leading zero (0 to 23, even with AM/PM display)

Answer (score 2):

Not all locale support this format of `QDateTime` output.

For result you are need create variable [`QLocale`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale-members.html) with parameters locale(language, country), which support it. For example:

```
QLocale eng(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedStates);
```

Then you can use [`QLocale::toString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#toString-6) method with chosen locale like this:

```
qDebug() << eng.toString(datetime,  "yyyy MMMM dd@HH.mm.ss zzz ap");
```

Works for me at your example. And this way don't substitute your native locale.